# SQL: How to delete some characters from field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking forward to deleting 36 characters if the first 4 match the search.

Example:

Search: ABCD

Input:
`CDBAhdjashbjhjk833h12kj3h21jk3h21123ABCD32872879dhc37cdkx76lx743hdadasd7CDBAhdjashbjhjk833h12kj3h21jk3h21123`

Result:
`CDBAhdjashbjhjk833h12kj3h21jk3h21123CDBAhdjashbjhjk833h12kj3h21jk3h21123`

As you can see `"ABCD32872879dhc37cdkx76lx743hdadasd"` was deleted from the row.

How can I make this possible on sql?

I'm trying this method since I was doing everything with php but some fetched data is higher than the string's default limit which is 4096.

Thank you

PD: Using MSSQL.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR (MAX) = 'CDBAhdjashbjhjk833h12kj3h21jk3h21ABCD32872879dhc37cdkx76lx743hdadasd7CDBAhdjashbjhjk833h12kj3h21jk3h21'

DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ABCD'

DECLARE @test varchar(max)

DECLARE @test1 varchar(max)

DECLARE @index int, @len int

set @len = LEN(@var)
print @len

set @index = CHARINDEX(@Search,@Var)

set @test = substring(@var,0,@index)

set @test1 = substring(@var,@index+36,@len)

select @test+@test1
```

this should help... sorry for the naming convention

Comment: Exactly what I was going to go for. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is plain Standard SQL:

```
CASE
   WHEN POSITION('ABCD' IN col) > 0 
   THEN SUBSTRING(col FROM 1 FOR POSITION('ABCD' IN col) - 1)
     || SUBSTRING(col FROM POSITION('ABCD' IN col) + 36)
   ELSE col
END
```

Edit after adding SQL Server tag:

```
CASE
   WHEN CHARINDEX('ABCD', col) > 0 
   THEN SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('ABCD', col)  - 1)
      + SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('ABCD', col)  + 36, 5000)
   ELSE col
END
```